# How to compute marginal effects in a Tobit model using R?

Tags: r, regression, tobit-regression

is anybody familiar with the `tobit()` command using the package AER? I'm searching for a command to compute the marginal effects for y (not for the latent variable y*). It seems to be $\phi(x\beta/\sigma)\beta$, where $\phi$ is the std.normal cumulative distribution function. But how can I compute those effects with R?